# XSLT processing issue on VSTO project. It works fine on WPF project

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, saxon

I'm using latest `version 9.9.1.5` of [Saxon XSLT processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_XSLT) to process some `XML` files in my [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) project on `VS2019 - ver 16.3.10`. The processor correctly processes the XML files. But when I use the exact same code on a [VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) project with exact same files and exact same version of `Saxon`, I get the following `Saxon error` when processing the exact same XML file:

> > Saxon.Api.DynamicError
> >       HResult=0x80131500
> >       Message=Output character not available in this encoding (x2211)
> >       Source=saxon9he-api
> >       StackTrace:
> >        at Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer.Run(XmlDestination destination)
> >     .....

**Note**: The entity code `&#x2211;` is in the XML file and is for unicode Character [“∑” (U+2211)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2211).

**Question**: Why I'm getting the above error on a `VSTO` project with the exact same code and files that my `WPF` project has (with no such issue there)?

**XML file top declaration part**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-16" />
....
.....
```

**XSLT file top declaration part**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
        xmlns:om="http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath"
        xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        exclude-result-prefixes="saxon om xs m h"
        >

<xsl:import href="pmml2texfrag.xsl"/>

<xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
.....
.....
```

**Remark**: A Similar issue reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/5484374/) with some thoughts from Mike Kay (the author of `Saxon`). But in my case code works fine on `WPF` project and not on a `VSTo` project.

Comment: Can you show us minimal but complete code samples of XML, XSLT and C# to allow us to reproduce the problem? How does the "correct" result you get with your code under WPF look like if you declare the output encoding US-ASCII and method `text` but want to use characters like `x2211` that are not ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information here for us to work out (a) how the two scenarios differ, and (b) why the failure occurs. (For example, you've shown two stylesheet modules with different xsl:output declarations and it's not clear to me how they relate.)

However, if you are indeed using the text output method with encoding us-ascii and are attempting to output the non-ASCII character x2211, then you can certainly expect this failure.